# Sum Over Certain Grouped Rows

Tags: sql, presto

I have a data set that shows the number of guests and revenue for each category of consumer (consumer that has visited once, twice, 3 times, 4 times, 5 times, etc).

It looks like this:
[image]

My query to get that table above was:

`SELECT number_of_trans, COUNT(*) AS guest_count, SUM(amount) AS revenue
FROM customer_counting
GROUP BY number_of_trans
ORDER BY number_of_trans`

Now, I want to sum both guest_count and revenue and I want to sum them for the following categories: 1,2,3,4,5-7,and 8+.

So really 1,2,3, and 4 would remain the same but I would be summing within rows 5 - 7 and rows from row 8 and onwards.

How would I do this? The table I want is below (don't worry about the accuracy of the values):

[image]

I hope my question is understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler form of Gordon's proposal:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN number_of_trans < 5 THEN cast(number_of_trans as varchar)
    WHEN number_of_trans < 8 THEN '5-7'
    ELSE '8+' 
  END as freq_band, 
  COUNT(*) AS guest_count, 
  SUM(amount) AS revenue 
FROM customer_counting 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN number_of_trans < 5 THEN cast(number_of_trans as varchar)
    WHEN number_of_trans < 8 THEN '5-7'
    ELSE '8+' 
  END
ORDER BY freq_band
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` and a subquery (or CTE):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN number_of_trans < 5 THEN CAST(number_of_trans as varchar)
             WHEN number_of_trans < 8 THEN '5-7'
             ELSE '8+'
        END) as grp,
       SUM(guest_count) as guest_count, SUM(revenue) as revenue
FROM (SELECT number_of_trans, COUNT(*) AS guest_count, SUM(amount) AS revenue
      FROM customer_counting
      GROUP BY number_of_trans
     ) x
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(number_of_trans);
```

Comment: shouldn't there be quotes around 8+?

Comment: I think that query could be made simpler by putting the case when into the inner group by?